# Browser HTTP Cache Force Invalidation for given REST API

Tags: http, browser-cache, cache-control

I have a service endpoint /api/endpoint which shall be used to fetch some JSON formatted data from my webpage in the browser. This data is never supposed to change, until the user logs out and clears his session.
I am looking to use Cache-Control headers to cache the API response for further page loads and API calls to /api/endpoint, but I need a way to clear this cache for this endpoint /api/endpoint when the user triggers a logout from the browser, is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using PHP for your webpage why dont you use session Variables?

See W3C for further guides: https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp

Comment: The webpage shall be in ReactJS, but ideally there are other webpages managed by other teams, that can be using any other JS framework, but they all use our service endpoint as a central / core feature to fetch some data on their pages.